# Ошибка в выборке из базы

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <?php 
$bd = mysql_connect("localhost","molod","1234");
mysql_select_db("molod",$bd);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id , title , mini_img ,text , autor , data FROM article ",$bd);
$my_zam = mysql_fetch_array('$result');

?>
```

Хотел вытащить поля `id, title, mini_img, text, autor, data`;

Comment: А что вы хотели сделать?

Comment: mysql_error() и mysql_errno() после строки запроса вам должны помочь

Answer (score 1):

> Цитата
> $my_zam = mysql_fetch_array('$result');

а мне вот кажется что в этом проблема. Зачем в функцию передавать переменную которая хранит ссылку на результат выборки в качестве строки?
должно быть
    $my_zam = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: Именно это, хотя там дальше могут быть и другие ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bd = mysql_connect("localhost","molod","1234") or die("Не подключаюсь почему-то :(");
mysql_select_db("molod",$bd);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `mini_img`, `text`, `autor`, `data` FROM `article`",$bd);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
$my_zam = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

P/S/ Если в запросе перечислены все поля, то проще его сделать таким:

```
SELECT * FROM `article`
```

Comment: звёздочку вообще лучше не использовать, потому как потом, чтоб увидеть какие поля выбираются, приходится лезть в базу

Comment: =) смешно... Вы вообще о чем? Зачем лезть в базу чтоб посмотреть какие поля? Если *, то выбираются все! А вместо mysql_fetch_array() использовать mysql_fetch_assoc(), и если не помнишь как называется поле, то что трудного вывести массив через print_r()?

Answer (score -1):

`"SELECT id , title , mini_img ,text , autor , data FROM article ",$bd)` - запятая вместо точки стоит перед $db

Comment: Где ????????

Comment: ,$bd) - тут

Comment: все правильно, там запятая и должна быть. Параметры функции перечисляются через запятую, а не через точку

Comment: ммм, точно, не о том подумал